# how does read(3) handle when nbyte < 0?

Tags: read

I couldn't find any behavior defined in the man page for read(3). My guess would be that it either throws an error or it just returns 0. But if someone could confirm any defined behavior that would be great. Or if the behavior is specified as being undefined somewhere then stating that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2):

Such a situation cannot happen by definition (at least under [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/read.html) and later). The `nbyte` argument to `read()` is a `size_t` and that's an unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the prototype of the `read` function:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Since the `count` argument is a `size_t` which is unsigned, if you try to pass a negative number eg. `read(fd, buf, -20)` (and you're running a 2's complement machine ;-)) that will be interpreted as a very large `count`, outside the range of successful return values -- `read()` returns the number of bytes read as a `ssize_t`, a **signed** integer of the same size as `size_t`.

In that case the following applies:

> If the value of nbyte is greater than `{SSIZE_MAX}`, the result is
> implementation-defined.

This is on [linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> On  Linux,  `read()`  (and  similar  system  calls) will transfer at most
> `0x7ffff000` (`2,147,479,552`) bytes, returning the number of  bytes  actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.)

In practice, a `read()` with a `count` larger than `SSIZE_MAX` results in an `EFAULT`, because it's impossible to fit the memory block starting at `buf` and extending for `count` bytes within the address space of the process.

On *bsd:

> `read()` and `pread()` may return the following error:
>
> `[EINVAL]`           nbytes was larger than `SSIZE_MAX`

And the same on solaris:

> `EINVAL`

> The nbyte argument overflowed an `ssize_t`.

Note: the openbsd [manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/read.2#CAVEATS) makes mention of systems where `read()` could return a negative value on success; if you know such a system, please add info about it here or in the comments.

Comment: 2's complement does not figure in, ISO C defines the result regardless of signed integer representation.

Comment: On many operating systems, GNU/Linux included, processes can alloate more memory tzhan SSIZE_MAX, so it's not clear why EFAULT would be generated. Additionally, in practise, most operating systems simply reduce the count and simply return fewer octets than requested, which is legal by POSIX (Linux does this for example).

Comment: @RememberMonica Linux [checks](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c#L469) before everything if the whole buffer is within the address space of the process, and if not, fails with `EFAULT` (this is also documented in the manpage; `EFAULT` could also be returned later, if the buffer is not backed by any memory). Could you give an example of a Linux running machine where you would able to fit a buffer > SSIZE_MAX within the address space of a process?

Comment: As to 2's complement, doesn't the ISO C standard basically say (in a roundabout way) that signed -> unsigned int of the same size should happen as if the same bit pattern would be reinterpreted as an unsigned int on a 2's complement machine?

Comment: the address space of a 32 bit process can be larger (e.g. 3GB) than the largest ssize_t value (er.g. ~2GB).

Comment: as for 2's complement, yes, it kind of says that. the point being that the conversion is well defined and the same, regardless of whether it uses 2c or not.